# RegEx pattern is only matching on the second alternation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This pattern was taken from the accepted answer here: [Regex - Extracting volume and chapter numbers from book titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373513/regex-extracting-volume-and-chapter-numbers-from-book-titles)

I stripped out the Vol/Volume matching since I'm only concerned with Chapter #s

RegEx: `(?i)(((?:C|chapter\s+)(\d+)) | (([a-z]+)\s+Chapter\b))`

Sample Text (matches in bold):

> Blabla Vol.1 **chapter 2**
>   ABCD in the era of XYZ volume 2 **First Chapter**  
>   Blah **blah chapter 2** <------ wrong
>   Lablah V6**C7** 2002
>   FooBar Vol6 **C3** by Dr. Foo Bar
>   Regex: A tool in Hell V1 **Eleventh Chapter**

Notice "Blah blah chapter 2" is matching on "blah chapter" instead of "chapter 2"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Along with the assertion via @SebastianProske, it is better written as `(?i)((c(?:hapter\s+)?(\d+)) | (([a-z]+)\s+chapter\b(?!\s+\d)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex engine first and foremost matches character by character from left to right. The order of alternations only matters, if more than one alternative can be matched at the same position.

If you want to avoid your second alternative to match chapter, if it is followed by a number, you should explicitly state so, using e.g. a negative lookahead.

`(?i)(((?:C|chapter\s+)(\d+))|(([a-z]+)\s+Chapter\b(?!\s+\d+)))`

This will match as follows:

```
Blabla Vol.1 chapter 2 --> chapter 2
ABCD in the era of XYZ volume 2 First Chapter --> First Chapter
Blah blah chapter 2 --> chapter 2
Lablah V6C7 2002 --> C7
FooBar Vol6 C3 by Dr. Foo Bar --> C3
Regex: A tool in Hell V1 Eleventh Chapter --> Eleventh Chapter
```

Answer (score 1):

The second alternative is always matching first. The way I would fix this is using a negative lookahead so the second alternative can not match where the first one matches.

```
(?i)((?:C|chapter\s+)(\d+))|(?!.*\d+)(([a-z]+)\s+chapter\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Regex, it checks the last two Words according to your rule, you must set the multiline option, if you pass the titles in multiline text:

```
(?i)(\w+\schapter$)|(chapter\s\d+$)
```

Note it uses `$` sign to indicate end of line